# Select users within given kilometers

Tags: php, laravel

I want to filter users in my database using given distance.

In database I have city, longitude and latitude. Now we should write in form just city and distance from that city and script should return all users near that city within given kilometers.

How can I achieve that?

This is my code:

```
if ($request->has('city')) {              
    $from_latitude = app('geocoder')->geocode($data['residence'])->get()->first()->getCoordinates()->getLatitude(); 
    $from_longitude = app('geocoder')->geocode($data['residence'])->get()->first()->getCoordinates()->getLongitude();

    $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) {
        $raw = \DB::raw('ROUND ( ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$from_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) ) AS distance');
        return $query->select('*')->addSelect($raw)->orderBy( 'distance', 'ASC' )->groupBy('distance')->having('distance', '<=', $distance);
   });
}
```

Comment: Please add details about _but that's not working.._ in your question. Error? Wrong result?

Comment: I don't understand that fragment having('distance'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not able to understand your problem. So i have done this in one of my project hope you get some idea from this answer

```
$latitude = 30.9193;
$longitude = 75.8309;
$users = DB::table('users');

// for km
$users->whereRaw("( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(".$longitude.") ) + sin ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) <=3.3)")->get();
// for miles
$users->whereRaw("( 3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(".$longitude.") ) + sin ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) <=3.3)")->get();
```

Hope it will helps you!

Comment: But where is distance from city?

Comment: you need to give distance where i added statcic value 3.3 @Programmmereg

Comment: How to change it on kilometers?

Comment: instead of 3959 put 6371 for km

Comment: yah you can do 6371